# Jquery - all autocomplete shows result at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using two independent autocomplete on same page.
            For ex. User Name, City. If I am search for username and type some character (ex. ab) and  without selecting any value. 
I am  shift to next text box which is city autocomplete and type character to search city.
    My Requirement is username autocomplete should display on page till I will not selecting any value from dropdown.
    In short I will see username, city autocomplete at a time.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#txt_user_name").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.get("abc.com/ajax/user", {
                q: request.term,
            }, function (data) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.fld_user_name,
                    value: item.fld_user_name,
                }
            }));
            }, "JSON");
        }
    });

    $("#txt_user_name").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.get("abc.com/ajax/city", {
                q: request.term,
            }, function (data) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.fld_city_name,
                    value: item.fld_city_name,
                }
            }));
            }, "JSON");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
UserName : <input type="text" id="txt_user_name" />
City : <input type="text" id="txt_city" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to provide us with some of your code?

Comment: You made a typo. On which elements are you applying autocomplete ?